# Converting milliseconds to months and years is not working properly

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java which seeks to convert milliseconds to years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
public class convertexercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Current Time in milliseconds = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
          long[] converter = new long [6];
          converter[0] = System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365); // years
          converter[1] = System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30); // months
          converter[2] = System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // days
          converter[3] = System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60); // hours
          converter[4] = System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60); // minutes
          converter[5] = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000; // seconds
          System.out.print(converter[0] + " years, " + converter[1] + " months, " + converter[2] + " days, " + converter[3] + " hours, " + converter[4] + " minutes, " + converter[5] + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

My program is able to convert `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the correct number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds. However when converting to months and years, it gets the wrong values (1045 years and -903 months which are obviously wrong values).

What exactly have I done wrong when converting to years and months?

Comment: Why dont you try Java [Calendar class] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_calendar.htm) to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use LocalDate Api ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get an integer range overflow. The number `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365` is too large to fit into an integer.

Instead do the calculations with long numbers:

```
converter[0] = System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365); // years
```

and so on.

Making the 1000 a long constant, forces long integer arithmetic for all the multiplications.